# SQL Statement to total all employee records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sql statement that is missing all employee names.

Table employee_list contains all employees for the company.

Table apps contain the employee that is assigned to the app

Table details contains the total dollar amount for the order

My query will not group and total for employees that did not have any apps. For example employee John had 5 apps for $250, Bill had 2 apps for $75 and Henry had 0 apps for $0 (no rows in apps or details table for Henry).

My query returns:

```
John   5   250.00
Bill   2    75.00
```

I need it to return

```
John   5   250.00
Bill   2    75.00
Henry  0     0.00
```

Any ideas? Here is my current code

`SELECT    employee_list.Fullname,
            count(apps.acntnum),
            sum(details.cost)
FROM employee_list
    left join apps on employee_list.Fullname=apps.EmployeeName
    LEFT JOIN details ON (apps.ID=details.ObjOwner_ID AND details.Active=1)
Group BY 
    employee_list.Fullname`

Comment: please provide table definition along with some sample data, so we can have a better idea. you might want to mention foreign keys as well

Comment: Please be more careful in your tag choices. MySql and Sql Server are very different database engines.

Comment: This query is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with all the other answers, however, you could also try this....

```
SELECT employee_list.Fullname,
(SELECT count(apps.acntnum) FROM apps WHERE employee_list.Fullname=apps.EmployeeName) AS Cnt,
(SELECT sum(details.cost) FROM apps LEFT JOIN details ON (apps.ID=details.ObjOwner_ID AND details.Active=1) WHERE employee_list.Fullname=apps.EmployeeName) AS cost
FROM employee_list
```

This will always return the full list of employees, and separately go and count/sum the other values.
This answer does not take performance into account.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is to be using a LEFT JOIN from your employee_list table and any subsequent tables you're joining to, and to not do anything that will filter out NULLs from the right-hand tables (because the NULLs would be for the 'missing' rows).

Your query is fine, but I suspect you're using it in a wider query, where you may inadvertently have an INNER JOIN or mention one of the columns in a WHERE clause.